# getElementbyId causing browser to crash

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a project for my class that requires me to change a banner image every 5 seconds for an unspecified amount of time. I'm using setInterval to do this, but I think it's causing a problem with my function. After 30sec-1min the browser crashes.

**HTML**

```
<body onload="startImgLoop();">
    <img id="banner" alt="Banner Image" />
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function startImgLoop()
{           
    var img = document.getElementById("banner");
    img.src = pictures[index];

    setInterval(startImgLoop, 5000);

    if (index == 5)
        index = 0;
    else index++;
}
```

When the browser crashes it asks me if I want to stop the script and it points to the first line of the loop where I'm using getElementById. Can someone please help explain why it's doing this?

Comment: It seems you used `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting an new interval every time the interval runs.  This will exhaust the timer resources and keep the browser too busy serving them all.

You can change it to this:

```
var index = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    var img = document.getElementById("banner");
    img.src = pictures[++index % pictures.length];
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What's the purpose of getting the remainder when setting the src?

Comment: @RandomlyKnighted - Getting the remainder replaces the four lines of code you had for preventing the index from going to high.  It's a common design pattern for repeatedly iterating through an array over and over because it always generates a value that is in the range of the array and the ++index guarentees that it goes up by one each time until the remainder wraps back to zero where it then starts increasing again.  Kind of a convenient trick.

Comment: I'll have to keep a snippet of that for future reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function startImgLoop()
{           
setInterval(goLoop, 5000);
}

function goLoop()
{           
var img = document.getElementById("banner");
img.src = pictures[index];


if (index == 5)
    index = 0;
else index++;
}
```

Try this, i dont test it. U should use setInterval to call the function, not put it inside the function